# Water resistance microphone for an outdoor kiosk

Tags: microphone, waterproof

Hi looking for a microphone to be used in an outdoor kiosk.
Until now we've been using this one: http://www.securitycamerasdirect.com/products/high-performance-microphone-pa3wp
But it is as now out of stock, and  probably not manufactured any more.
Anyone knows of a similar mic?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://www.countryman.com/emw-omnidirectional-lavalier
This is a professional lavaliere microphone and will  cost more but it should be worth it.